# How can I export a block created in a custom block library?

Tags: blocks, importing-exporting

I have created 3 custom blocks in /admin/structure/block/block-content and I am trying to export them from admin/config/development/configuration/single/export. There isn't any option to achieve this. I am able to export fields and field storage, but not blocks and their content.

How can I export a block created in a custom block library?

Comment: This is currently being worked on, according to https://www.drupal.org/node/2756331. https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_block seems to be an alternative for time being.